# Why wasn’t my chicken broth boiling in jars when I took it out of the pressure canner?

Tags: food-safety, canning, broth, pressure-canner

I pressure canned chicken broth in my electric pressure canner. When I took the jars out of the canner the broth was not boiling inside the jar. Should I be concerned? That has never happened before. All the jars have sealed.

Comment: Since the top was sealed properly, the vapor pressure of the steam builds up so that the steam and the liquid are now in equilibrium at the canning temperature - you won't get "boiling" inside the jar.